# Logarithms and expectation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

im just self learning probability and I have find pretty difficult to solve problems that involves composing a function.

For example, Let $X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}$ random variables **iid** and $f_{X}(x)= \frac{1}{x^{2}}$ when $x\geq 1$ and $f_{X}(x)=0$ in other cases and I have to find $\mathbb{E}[Y]$, when $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}logX_{i}$.

Whats the trick in case there is? I asked a friend and told me that it was a common trick but he didnt explained it and I havent been able to find it. Sorry if it is too elementary but im really stuck in here.

Hope you guys can help, thanks so much in advance. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By linearity of expectation, you have $$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[\log X_i]
= n\cdot \mathbb{E}[\log X_1] = n \int_{\mathbb{R}} dx f_X(x) \log x$$
the second-to-last equality since $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are identically distributed, and the last by the [Law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Now,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} dx f_X(x) \log x = \int_{1}^\infty dx \frac{\log x}{x^2} = 1
$$
by evaluating the integral.

Comment: Thanks so much sir! And what is the idea for $Y=min\{X_{1},...,X_{n}\}$? if they are identically distributed that means that we can choose any of the random variables lets say $X_{1}=min\{X_{1},...,X_{n}\}$?

Comment: No, that won't work here. An idea when dealing with minimums or maximums is to try and compute the cdf of Y. Indeed, the minimum of the $X_i$s will be greater than t if, and only if, all $X_i$s are greater than t; and then you can use independence.